# cloudsql to cloudsql migration permissions issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to use the gcp database migration tool to migrate a cloudsql postgres 9.6 instance to a cloudsql postgres 13 instance.

I set both `cloudsql.enable_pglogical` and `cloudsql.logical_decoding` to on with a flag in the UI, and restarted the instance, but I still get the following error when trying to run the migration with the postgres account.

Failure connecting to the source database. Make sure the user has the required privileges. Address the issues then Restart the migration job. Details: replication user postgres doesn't have sufficient privileges: replication user doesn't have USAGE privilege on schema pglogical in database postgres; replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.team_members, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.doc_comment_read, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.mailbox_google, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.doc_editor, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.mailbox_microsoft, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.enrollment_whitelist, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.group_members, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public.team_invites, replication user doesn't have SELECT privilege on table public...

Comment: Did you try to grant these privilege on the current user?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a couple of things.

1. You cannot use postgres user to do this migration, as the postgres user does not have the replication attributes.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users

`The postgres user is part of the cloudsqlsuperuser role, and has the following attributes (privileges): CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN. It does not have the SUPERUSER or REPLICATION attributes.`

2. You need to make sure to use the owner of the DB to do the migration, not the postgres user.
3. You have to give your user permissions on the pglogical schema.

`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA pglogical TO my_user;`
`GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA pglogical TO my_user;`

4. Add the replication attribute to your user(you'll need to do this from the postgres user)

`ALTER ROLE my_user with REPLICATION;`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that it is completely possible to use the `postgres` user for replication. You need to set the replication attribute for it

```
ALTER ROLE postgres with REPLICATION;
```

and then [grant the necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgresql-to-alloydb/configure-source-database#configure-your-source-databases-postgres) (look at point 3).